# Why does the Fuse iterator adapter not work as expected?

Tags: iterator, rust

I'm experimenting with the `Fuse` iterator adapter and am getting unexpected results ([Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=fn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20i1%20%3D%20(1..3).scan(1%2C%20%7C_%2C%20x%7C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20x%20%3C%202%20%7B%20None%20%7D%20else%20%7B%20Some(x)%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20i1.next())%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20i1.next())%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20i1.next())%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%22)%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20i2%20%3D%20(1..3).scan(1%2C%20%7C_%2C%20x%7C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20x%20%3C%202%20%7B%20None%20%7D%20else%20%7B%20Some(x)%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D).fuse()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20i2.next())%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20i2.next())%3B%20%2F%2F%20This%20should%20print%20None%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20i2.next())%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%22)%3B%0A%7D%0A&version=stable&backtrace=0)):

```
fn main() {
    let mut i1 = (1..3).scan(1, |_, x| {
        if x < 2 { None } else { Some(x) }
    });
    println!("{:?}", i1.next());
    println!("{:?}", i1.next());
    println!("{:?}", i1.next());
    println!("");

    let mut i2 = (1..3).scan(1, |_, x| {
        if x < 2 { None } else { Some(x) }
    }).fuse();
    println!("{:?}", i2.next());
    println!("{:?}", i2.next()); // This should print None
    println!("{:?}", i2.next());
    println!("");
}
```

Which prints:

```
None
Some(2)
None

None
Some(2)
None
```

Iterator `i1` is returning what I expect. It returns `None`, then `Some(2)`, then `None`. `i2` is the same iterator adapted with `fuse()`. Fuse should make it return `None` after the first `None`, and since the first value it returns is `None` that should be the only value it returns. However, it behaves the same as `i1`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR Summary: This [was a bug](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/41964) and is fixed in Rust 1.19 and newer.

I'm pretty sure you are doing nothing wrong. This appears to be either a bug (my guess) or a *very* confusing interaction. Check out this expanded example:

```
#![feature(fused)]

fn dump<I: Iterator<Item = i32>>(label: &str, mut iter: I) {
    println!("= Running: {}", label);
    for _ in 0..10 {
        println!("{:?}", iter.next());
    }
    println!("");
}

fn boxed_internal_fuse() -> Box<Iterator<Item = i32>> {
    Box::new((1..3)
        .scan(1, |_, x| if x < 2 { None } else { Some(x) })
        .fuse())
}

fn boxed_no_fuse() -> Box<Iterator<Item = i32>> {
    Box::new((1..3)
        .scan(1, |_, x| if x < 2 { None } else { Some(x) }))
}

use std::iter::FusedIterator;
fn boxed_no_fuse_but_fused() -> Box<FusedIterator<Item = i32>> {
    Box::new((1..3)
        .scan(1, |_, x| if x < 2 { None } else { Some(x) }))
}

fn main() {
    let i1 = (1..3)
        .scan(1, |_, x| if x < 2 { None } else { Some(x) });
    dump("Scan", i1);
    
    let i2 = (1..3)
        .scan(1, |_, x| if x < 2 { None } else { Some(x) })
        .fuse();
    dump("Fuse<Scan>", i2);
    
    dump("Box<Fuse<Scan>>", boxed_internal_fuse());
    dump("Fuse<Box<Iterator>>", boxed_no_fuse().fuse()); // All `None`s
    dump("Fuse<Box<FusedIterator>>", boxed_no_fuse_but_fused().fuse());
}
```

The trick is that `FusedIterator` is a unstable trait that is aimed at improving the efficiency. It lets `Iterator::fuse` know that it's a no-op.

However, in this case, the conditions are necessary but not sufficient:

```
impl<B, I, St, F> FusedIterator for Scan<I, St, F>
    where I: FusedIterator, F: FnMut(&mut St, I::Item) -> Option<B> {}
```

It's true that if the *underlying iterator* is `FusedIterator` and starts returning `None`, `scan` will keep returning `None`. However, that's not the only way to get `None` — the *closure* can also return `None`!

Comment: I've opened [issue 41964](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/41964), let's see what happens.

Comment: I thought it had to be a bug, but wasn't aware of this sort of trait specialization magic, so was stuck looking at the code for `Fuse` itself which looked fine. Interestingly, the only other Rust question I've asked also turned out to be a bug discovery.

Comment: @wingedsubmariner [you've asked *two* others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1224627+%5Brust%5D+is%3Aq), and counting bugs before Rust 1.0 is practically cheating ^_^

Comment: Ah you're right, not sure how I didn't find that one. ^_^

Comment: Summary: This was a bug and is fixed in Rust 1.19 and newer.